# Error failed to open stream: Permission denied when upload a vodeo

Tags: laravel, file-upload, dropzone.js

When Upload a video in laravel 7 in windows i have this error

```
message: "fopen(C:\wamp64\www\jahanzirnevis\public): failed to open stream: Permission denied"
```

But when upload image that work and no error.
My Code For Upload:

```
public function putFileAsPublic(string $name,UploadedFile $file,string  $type)
{
    return Storage::disk('public')
        ->putFileAs($type,$file,$name);
}
```

and

```
private function getType()
{
    return [
        'image/jpeg'=>'image',
        'image/png'=>'image',
        'application/octet-stream'=>'video',
        'video/mp4'=>'video',
        'application/zip'=>'zirnevis',
        'application/x-zip-compressed'=>'zirnevis',
    ][$this->file->getClientMimeType()];
}
```

and

```
private function putFileIntoStorage()
{
    $this->storageManager->putFileAsPublic('JahanZirnevis.ir_'.$this->file->getClientOriginalName(),$this->file,$this->getType());
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have given `read-write` permission to public folder.

Comment: @SahilGupta how can give this permission in widows?

Comment: right-click on the folder. choose properties and select the Security tab. Edit the permission or allow full control.

Comment: @SachinKumar I change permission but not work and i have this error

Comment: Try by clearing the cache, views and config using php artisan command.